# Flutter: How to make this type bubble in chat message?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

How to make this type bubble in chat message?

Current Output

[image]

Require Output
[image]

Tried below code but didn't get the top side left part of curve. Is there any packages or lib. available to make this type of custom shapes in flutter.

Code to produce current output.

Thanks in Advance.

```
Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 30),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            Stack(
              overflow: Overflow.visible,
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                  height: 40,
                  width: 40,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    border: Border.all(color: Colors.white, width: 3),
                    shape: BoxShape.circle,
                    image: DecorationImage(
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                      image: const AssetImage(
                          'assets/images/composite-corporate-group-photos.jpg'),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Positioned(
                  top: 37,
                  child: Padding(
                    padding:const EdgeInsets.only(left: 3),
                    child: Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                          horizontal: 20, vertical: 8),
                      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                        color: pinkColor,
                        shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                        boxShadow: [
                          BoxShadow(
                            color: Colors.grey,
                            blurRadius: 4.0,
                          ),
                        ],
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                          bottomRight: Radius.circular(22.0),
                          bottomLeft: Radius.circular(22.0),
                          topRight: Radius.circular(22.0),
                        ),
                      ),
                      child: Text(
                        widget.text,
                        style: const TextStyle(
                          fontFamily: 'PoppinsRegular',
                          fontSize: 16,
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            )
          ],
        ),
      );
```

Comment: use `CustomClipper<Path> for building shape.

Comment: @AbhayKoradiya i tried custom clipper but didn't get exact math to get that shape

Answer (score 1):

I had tried `CustomPainter` first. But can't get success due to some math issue.

Finally got success with `BoxDecoration`. Don't know my solution is good or bad. But

Please let me know if anyone have another best approach.

```
class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  double width = 0, height = 60;

  MyWidget({this.width, this.height});

  @override
  _MyWidgetState createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    if (widget.width == 0) {
      widget.width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          height: widget.height,
          width: widget.width,
          color: colorPink,
          child: Material(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
              bottomLeft: Radius.circular(widget.height / 2),
            ),
            child: Row(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  width: widget.height,
                  height: widget.height,
                  decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                    shape: BoxShape.circle,
                    image: new DecorationImage(
                      image: ExactAssetImage('images/pokemon/u83.jpg'),
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    ),
                    border: new Border.all(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      width: 4.0,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          height: widget.height,
          width: widget.width,
          child: Material(
            color: colorPink,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
              bottomLeft: Radius.circular(widget.height / 3),
              bottomRight: Radius.circular(widget.height / 3),
              topRight: Radius.circular(widget.height / 3),
            ),
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0),
              child: Container(
                alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                child: Text(
                  "Some text here....",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    fontSize: 15.0,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

check image Output [image]

Answer (score -2):

Good design to build on flutter.

here is the post, you can checkout!

```
  Custom paint in flutter
```